# My App doesn't show up on the market

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I've found today that my recently published app on the Android Market,
is not showing up on this device Market: [Samsung Apollo](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-phones/mobile-phones/smartphone/GT-I5800DKAXEU/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=specification).

I've already followed this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#strategies)  to make my app accesible to almost all devices configurations
and it still don't show on that device's Market.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have asked 16 questions and accepted only half? That doesn't make people want to answer your question, if it was answerable by StackOverflow, which it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the copy protection functionality when uploading the apk?

That can be the issue.

Comment: Yes, I did. Is that the problem?

Comment: It might. I have that on one of my apps and disabling it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android did you build against? Does that phone run a compatible version?